# Need help setting up Selenium for Safari in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, selenium, safari

I have the safari extension installed and enabled.
I have the following libraries in the build path:

```
selenium-java-2.45.0jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
```

with this I try to create a `SafariDriver` and get the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at AI2048.main(AI2048.java:7)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 10229 ms
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'justin-macbook-pro.local', ip: '10.0.0.6', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.2', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.start(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.startClient(SafariDriver.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:42)
    at ...
```

I am not sure what I am missing, could someone help me out?

Comment: One of the common problem is the not suitable version of the driver. Play around versions

Comment: @ema where can I find earlier versions of the driver?

Comment: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html. Also check it : http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7801